How to visualize conditional maximum likelihood estimation?
In Probabilistic Machine Learning (Murphy, 2022, p. 8) I'm stuck in this part:

1.2.1.6 Maximum likelihood estimation When fitting probabilistic models, it is common to use the negative log probability as our loss
function:
$$ 
l(y, f(x; \theta )) = − \log p(y|f(x; \theta)) \tag{1.13}
 $$
The reasons for this are explained in Section 5.1.6.1, but the
intuition is that a good model (with low loss) is one that assigns a
high probability to the true output $y$ for each corresponding input
$x$.

$\DeclareMathOperator*{\argmin}{arg\,min}$
I've seen MLE in the form $\argmin_\theta -\log p(\theta ;x)$ and it is intuitive in the sense that I'm trying to find the parameter $\theta$ such that the likelihood of observing the data $x$ is the highest. It is not hard to visualize that. For example, we could just think of normally distributed points on the $x$ axis and see that a normal distribution would 'fit' the data quite well.
Without getting into information theory, I would appreciate the answer for the following questions:
But what about conditional distributions? What is the intuition behind trying to find the parameter $\theta$ which makes the probability of $y$, the true distribution, given the predicted probability distribution, $f(x;\theta )$, the most likely? What guarantees that $y$ has anything to do with the predicted $\hat y$? How $y = \hat y$ minimizes this function? And finally, can someone explain how would one calculate that for, say, $y = [0, 1, 0]$ (a one-hot vector representing class 2), and $f(x;\theta ) = [0.15, 0.85, 0]$.

With MLE you assume that the data are drawn from a distribution $p$ that is defined by some parameters $\theta$ and then you try to estimate $\theta$ by minimizing $-\log p$. With probabilistic models you don't make any assumptions about $p$; instead you use some input data $x$ and a neural network characterized by parameters $\theta$ to derive the probability of $x$ belonging to some discrete class.  The label in this case is $y=(0,1,0)$; the model returns $(0.15,0.85,0)$. So $p(y|f(x;\theta))=0.85$.

So is it just notation? I mean, we are not using Bayes rule or directly calculating the conditional probability (P(AUB)/P(B)). How can one simply assume that the conditional probability of y given some prediction is just the “index” of y at the prediction? What if y was not a degenerate distribution but something like (0.10, 0.80, 0.10)

The neural network generates some vector $(\pi_1,\ldots,\pi_n)$ for $n$ classes; so the probability of $x$ belonging to class $i$ is $\pi_i$. A model that tends to mislabel will assign low probability to the correct label which means $-\log\pi_i$ will be a large positive number and this is a property that we want for loss functions in general.

Sorry, I meant P(A and B) not P(AUB)

Yes, Ted. Intuitively that makes sense, but why is it a conditional probability if it is not calculated by any conditional probability formula?

This is the standard formulation for a likelihood function. For example, say we want to use maximum likelihood to estimate the probability of heads. We toss a coin $n$ times and observe $y_1,\ldots,y_n$ where $y_i=1$ if heads and zero otherwise. The parameter in the model is the probability of heads $\pi$. So for the likelihood function we write $p(y_1,\ldots,y_n|\pi )=\prod_{i=1}^n \pi^{y_i} (1-\pi )^{1-y_i}$. As always we optimise negative loglikelihood so we use, $-\log p(y_1,\ldots,y_n|\pi)$. So this is a conditional probability for a point estimate  of $\pi$.

In the book the autor makes clear the notation difference between conditional probability “p(y|x)” and parameter of a probabilistic model “f(y;x)”. Intuitively it all makes sense, but where is the rule that says that p(y|f(x;theta)) = index of y in the prediction vector, I thought we’d use the conditional probability formula for that.

Maybe I haven’t studied enough and my questions are too trivial and confusing for that reason. I’ll do a deep dive into probability and statistics to see if that changes. Thanks.

That's the likelihood function! Lets say your model generates $(\pi_1,\pi_2,\pi_3)$. The likelihood for a single observation is $p((y_1,y_2,y_3)|(\pi_1,\pi_2,\pi_3))=\pi_1^{y_1}\pi_2^{y_2}\pi_3^{y_3}$; or $-\log p((y_1,y_2,y_3)|(\pi_1,\pi_2,\pi_3)) = -\left( y_1 \log\pi_1 +y_2 \log\pi_2 + y_3 \log\pi_3  \right)$. We can only have one-hot encoding for $(y_1,y_2,y_3)$ hence the result. Remember Bayes theorem is $p(A|B)=p(A \wedge B)/p(B)$; for a point estimate of $B$ ($B$ takes one specific value) there is no $p(B)$. So the conditional means "probability of event $A$ given parameter $B$".

Indeed! That made it clearer. So, suppose somehow I know p(A∧B) and p(B) (which in practice almost never happens). Would the ratio of these probabilities be equal to the probability of A conditioned by the parameter B in the way specified above (y^pi)? That is, can I interpret that the probability of event A given that B has already happened as the same as the probability of event A given parameter B?

Lets say the probability of heads $\pi$ has some distribution $p(\pi)$. Then $p(y_1,\ldots,y_n \wedge \pi)=\prod_{i=1}^n \pi^{y_i} (1-\pi)^{1-y_i} p(\pi)$ and $p(y_1,\ldots,y_n | \pi)=\prod_{i=1}^n \pi^{y_i} (1-\pi)^{1-y_i}$.


What guarantees that  has anything to do with the predicted ̂ ?

This is a great question. In general, you don't have guarantees. Consider for example the case where you are optimizing over all measurable functions. You would choose a function which maximizes the likelihood (and overfits). If your set of models is constrained (eg regularized) appropriately, then under some conditions the selected model will predict $y$ well.

How =̂  minimizes this function?

I think there is some confusion here, the notation used in the book is unclear (at least to me, after just skimming a few pages). The notation $p(y|f(x;\theta))$ represents the probability of the label being equal to $y$ given the value of $f(x;\theta)$. I think you should look closely at the examples from the preceding pages to get an idea of what the notation should represent. In any case, I wouldn't get to hung up on this (it is still page 8 :) ), I don't think the notation is really formal or extra clean and explicit here.
For intuition, consider this case: If $\theta^*$ is the optimal choice, and gives perfect prediction accuracy, then $f(x;\theta^*)$ is always equal to $y$. So now $p(y|f(x;\theta^*))$ is just $p(y|y)$ which is of course 1.
